# How to SERVICE_START_NAME value for processes without a Name Service?

Tags: windows

I would like to check `SERVICE_START_NAME` value for processes on my Windows 7 machine that does not have any name services (obtain with `tasklist /SVC`), but just a PID.

For services with a name I usually do: `sc qc service_name`

Note: there are no Windows Service in the process maybe, but still the process is running and I would like to know if it is auto loaded on boot and also which user starts the process.

Comment: If `tasklist /SVC` doesn't show any service(s) in a process, then there isn't/aren't any service(s) in that process.

Comment: Ok, there are no Windows Service in the process maybe, but still the process is running and I would like to know if it is auto loaded on boot and also which user starts the process. I'm sorry I wasn't clear in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When and by whom was a Windows process started**

```
 CMD> wmic process {PID} get creationdate,parentprocessid

 Note: I'm sure this can be done with PowerShell as well, but it always
 takes me two or three times as long to use PowerShell so I rarely bother
```

*If* the parent process is still running, you can look at it with `tasklist` TaskManager etc. Note it is possible the original parent process exited and then a new process was assigned the same PID, so if the relationship doesn't make sense, look at the apparent parent's (!) creationdate also.

Or if you want to do this a lot, I recommend ProcessExplorer from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx with View / Show Process Tree. This displays child processes sorted under their parents (if still existing) and indented, making the relationships easy to see. It can also show the UserName for each process, see View / Select Columns.

**What processes are started at boot/login/etc**

There are lots of places in Windows where things can be configured that start processes automatically at boot, login, or other events including scheduled times. There are quite a few tools that try to make sense of these. I like Autoruns from the same webpage above; I don't know if it includes absolutely everything but it has always included everything I needed to look for.

(FWIW as of today ProcessExplorer and Autoruns are the first two of the Top 10 Downloads.)